# Magic Mouse: replace single finger swiping/scrolling with two finger swiping/scrolling

Tags: macos, mouse, bettertouchtool

I sometimes accidentally trigger the horizontal swipe/scroll gesture on my magic mouse. Especially in X11/Inkscape, if I work zoomed in on a big canvas, this often moves my canvas several screens to the right or left and I have to carefully swipe/scroll back to my original view.

I would like to make the swiping more explicit by allowing only two finger swipes, which should then just work as vertical/horizontal scroll gestures, as if I had triggered them on a normal mouse (with 2 scroll wheels).

`Preferences > Mouse > More Gestures > Swipe Between Pages (two fingers)` does not help. I also already tried to map (globally) single finger swipes and scroll actions in Better Touch Tool (BTT) to `No Action`. But they still work in all apps.

What else can I try, i.e., what other tools can I use or what other system settings can I change (via Terminal) to make it work?

*System specs*: Macbook Pro Retina, Magic Mouse, OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks), BTT 0.9985

**Update**: Please note that:

1. I had been using [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) version 0.9985 (as stated above)
2. I also tried [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) (some older version)

If someone provides a *detailed*, convincing solution that solves the above problem, I will try to reclaim my now *abandoned* Magic Mouse, validate the solution, and gladly accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

MagicPrefs (http://magicprefs.com) version 2.4.2 did the trick for me. Choose "Preferences" in the menu it puts in the upper right of the menu bar, then click on the "Configure Scrolling" button, and then uncheck the row of checkboxes to the right of the label "One Finger Scrolling:"

No more scrolling with one finger!

Sadly, as the app notes, you can no longer use "momentum scrolls", where the page keeps scrolling after you have lifted up your fingers. You can't have it all, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the MagicPrefs pane (http://magicprefs.com)?

I suppose it can help. Or other tool that may help is BetterTouchTool (http://www.bettertouchtool.net).

Comment: Did you read all text in my original question? Yes, I already tried Better Touch Tool. However, I am now using Karabiner as my Mac-input hack method of choice that I will not combine with other tools to avoid unexpected results. And actually, I was so disappointed with the magic mouse that I gave it to a colleague of mine and use my old trusted 3-button Logitech mouse. I am happy now and I do not miss the magic mouse.

Comment: I can not even describe you how glad am I for this fact. I would gladly recommend at least to check the MagicPrefs pane, since you haven't even tried it :D 
Also read carefully and participate in the Q-A experience instead of trolling around.

Comment: There is no need to be upset and accuse people of trolling. The purpose of my comment was first to remind you that you should read all questions carefully and secondly provide an update on my current status with the magic mouse. On that regard, I also checked the MagicPrefs website that you linked, and recognized the tool as another tool I have been comprehensively experimenting with when I was using the magic mouse. I did not find a solution that would not regularly suffer from unwanted input. If someone provides a detailed solution to the described problem, I might try the magic mouse again.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like a strange solution, but you should try using your mouse on a different surface.

I recently changed my mouse mat/surface and this sort of strange Magic Mouse behaviour has all but disappeared.

My old surface was so used it has started to become shiny in patches. My guess is that these shiny patches are causing the mouse to report abnormal patterns of signals, which causes all manner of strange behaviour in general use.